# How to write an integer array in a file.And I want to read this array one by one(not character)

Tags: c++, file-io

How to write an integer array in a file.And I want to read this array one by one(not character).
Suppose I've a file which have integers:

```
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I want to use these integers as array.I have to read one by one element of array and store them in another array.
How to do this?

Comment: Open the file, use [`fscanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf), close the file.

Comment: @GoldRoger I disagree `fscanf`, the question is tagged c++!

Comment: Oops..didnt see the tag..OP ignore my comment

Comment: @OP You should show some efforts of what you already tried, and which particular obstacles, errors you got.

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as that.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

// Read from file into an array

std::ifstream file ("file.txt");
std:vector<int> v;
int i;
while ((file >> i))
    v.push_back(i);

// Write back into the file
std::ofstream file ("file.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);
for (int i : v)
    file << i << '\n';
```

Comment: _How to **write** an integer array ..._?!?

Comment: I thought he meant he wants to read from file and write into memory.

Comment: You're both right : _And I want to read this array one by one_, I was only addressing one part of the problem.